Central AC not cooling 2nd floor
The home is 2-yrs. old, 4000 sq. ft with 3 bedrooms, 3 bathrooms and open balcony on the 2nd floor.  The AC keeps the first level comfortable but the 2nd floor is very hot in summer.  Would a 2nd AC unit in attic resolve the problem?

Should first see if the duct work needs tuning, allow more air up than down.  See if the AC is big enough for the house size.  Insulation values and solar heating of the second floor.  I assume the last two was done right, but big windows letting sun in, does not help.

Is the second floor the top-most floor of the house or is there a third 'floor' called the attic? Is the attic insulated? I assume sliding or French doors to the balcony - does strong sun shine through the balcony door? If there is a distinct third floor attic, it needs to be insulated and venting to allow hot air to escape. Our century-old home has a large attic fan which pulls cooler air from the lower floors. Please edit your question to include more details about the construction of your house!

Yes, can you provide more details about the construction of your house?

Just to answer your question, yes it would. Here in South Florida it is a very common problem for second floors to get much hotter than the first and one AC unit on the first floor just doesn't hack it. AC air is cold and heavy and it's hard for the blower to raise that air to a second floor even if all the design figures are correct. So many homes add a second unit, but not in the attic because maintaining the unit, changing filters, can be difficult.  They usually add a condensing unit outside at grade level and run the pipes up and through the attic, to a newly installed air handler and thermostat on the second floor, usually in a closet. Now both units are easily accessible. One of many advantages to this arrangement is being able to individually control the cooling on each floor. It's the most expensive solution so checking out all the options in the comments should be done first.
